# why ng-plurazlize not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using simple example of ng-plurazlize .I don't why it is not printing value .can you please explain why it is not working ?

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/JnOAa2B0hHSL22hIL2MY?p=preview

```
<input type="text" ng-model='plCount'/>
    <h1><ng-plurazlize count="plCount" offset=when="{'0':'one','other':'{}are'}"></ng-plurazlize>

    </h1>
```

Comment: `'plurazlize' != 'pluralize'`

Comment: @Satpal still not working http://plnkr.co/edit/JnOAa2B0hHSL22hIL2MY?p=preview'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in there, plus your when parameter was wrong. Should be something like this:

```
<ng-pluralize count="plCount" when="{'0':'one','other':'{}are'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

You offset parameter is incorrect. This should be a number. For example:

```
<ng-pluralize count="plCount" offset=2 when="{'0':'one','other':'{}are'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

I have it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqxOlDnw6cHCbqlWBmk3?p=preview

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model='plCount' />
      <h1>
      <ng-pluralize count="plCount" offset=2 when="{'0':'one','other':'{}are'}">

      </ng-pluralize>
    </h1>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The JavaScript was missing too. I added it:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.plCount = '0';
})
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/36URWAIqKvxqV1yuvULh?p=preview when I write 1 it give error why

Comment: I see the issue. I have no idea why it is doing that. Looks like a bug. To fix it just add a when map for one, for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OEQQ277fmiEzwaH0GakC?p=preview